# htaccess deny main folder allow subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, directory, restriction

How do i create a htaccess file that denies access to a main folder, but allows access to a subfolder?

example: 
http://www.mysite.net/folder1 (deny acces) http://www.mysite.net/folder1/folder2 (allow acces)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to mod_rewrite then you can add some conditions into your config -

You could capture requests and rewrite them to a different place using

```
RewriteCond {REQUESTED_FILE} !^/?(.*)/+$
RewriteRule .....
```

Or to just block them

```
RewriteRule  !^/?(.*)/+$ - [F]
```

Comment: do i have to add this in my root htaccess or in my folder 1 htaccess

Comment: This would go in the root folder - not the subfolders.  It will basically block any request that does not start / and contain some text / numbers / symbols - folowed by another /

Comment: If your subfolders can be accessed using an index file an additional rule will be needed.